# In Spring Boot, does @ConfigurationProperties support property binding through SpEL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-expression-language

I am using Spring Boot 3.2.2 , JDK 21.

In Spring Boot, Does `@ConfigurationProperties` support property binding through SpEL?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, Does @ConfigurationProperties support property binding through SpEL? No.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.vs-value-annotation

[image]